# JQuery Accordion closes unintended when ajax-link from inside gets response

Tags: ajax, javascript, navigation

I'm working on a page where a user can click on ajaxified links inside a JQuery-Accordion-Widget.

Currently every time a link is clicked and the response is loaded, the accordion gets closed and it is not possible to click it anymore - but no JS-error is raised.

Did i miss something i have to call i.e. to change the focus ?

Thanks for your help,
piezo.

Comment: Just init the Accordion again on the ajax success.

Comment: This seems kind of hacky to me and i would like to not change the state of the accordion before the ajax-call..

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use one of the jQuery Accordion API functions to manually control the state of the accordion

e.g:

```
// getter
var active = $( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active" ); 
// setter
$( ".selector" ).accordion( "option", "active", 2 );
```

more info [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But my issue is, that i would like the accordion state like it is an change it if neccessary. I think i have to learn, which event on the accordion is triggered when the ajax returns.. - Any ideas?

Answer (score -2):

the event is ajaxSuccess on the child .ui-accordion-content divs